# Disable caps lock indicator on Webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

If you're in the latest version of Chrome, or in a Webkit nightly build, you'll notice that password fields have a nice new caps lock indicator baked right into the browser itself.

As far as I can tell, there does not appear to be any style changes related to this indicator. As such, I am having no luck finding a way to disable it, as our company uses a styled JavaScript solution for cross-browser caps-lock indicators.

Does anyone know of a way to disable this indicator in Webkit browsers?

Comment: Does `-webkit-appearance: none` or `textfield` solve anything?  I don't have a browser to test, but that's my best guess.

Comment: that's what i would suggest as per http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/webkit/css_-webkit-appearance.cfm

Comment: @apsillers Nope. This appears to not be set via any webkit style attributes.

Comment: What version exactly, and what OS?  I just looked at Chrome Canary (25) and the latest nightly Chromium on Windows 7 and couldn't get a caps lock indicator to come up on password fields.

Comment: @josh3736 Interesting. I'm on OSX and it shows in Chrome 22, Chrome Canary 23, and last night's Webkit nightly build. So I assume the next build of Safari will also have this present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a caps lock indicator to password text inputs is actually a feature of Mac OS X, not something specific to Chrome/Webkit.  In Windows and Linux versions of Chrome, there is no caps lock indicator.

I did find that adding `display: block` to the password field caused the indicator to go away in both Chrome and Safari.  However, given the fact that `display` has absolutely nothing to do with a caps lock indicator, I'd consider this an implementation detail (borderline bug) that is likely to be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

for what is worth 5 yrs later, I've solved it by setting

```php
input::-webkit-caps-lock-indicator {
    content: none;
}
```

Might not be the cleanest solution but does the job;

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not scriptable from JavaScript. It's inside the browser code itself. There may be a setting in the browser for it, but web pages have zero control over it.

Comment: Is it possible to apply feature-detection to identify the browser version containing the capslock indicator, so that the Javascript one can be disabled?

Comment: Well, he can simply check if the version of Webkit they're using is one of the versions with the caps lock indicator, then disable the javascript one if so.

Comment: @sgroves That's not feature detection, it's browser detection. THe idea of feature detection is that you say "this feature will cause problems - does this browser support it?" and you always get the correct answer back. If you use browser detection, you rely on keeping your detection script updated to cover newer browsers, which is undesirable

Comment: i know that. it's a potential solution though.

Comment: @Diodeus That's the same conclusion I came to, but I was hoping someone would know a way. One would think that anything that adds content and/or style to a page, even if it's baked into the browser code itself, would be controllable.

Comment: It's just like the "resize" handle on a textarea - it's there, but you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at `-webkit-appearence: caps-lock-indicator` could help you to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to use hacks, in that case. As a quick, but not very elegant solution try to draw DIV with `position: absolute` (out of the flow and will not break your markup) with not-transparent background above the indicator you want to hide.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be good either, as the arrow displays within the input itself. Covering the arrow would also cover any text that extended into the right side of the input.